# CORS issue with cached resources on alibaba cloud

Tags: cors, alibaba-cloud

I have a font file on alibaba OSS, I've set the `cors` origin to `https://*example.com`, when the font is loaded the first time by a sub domain there is no issue but when another sub domain tries to fetch the font there is `cors` origin conflict.

When the font is loaded the first time, it's origin is set as the first domain that loads it and its cached, so when another domain tries to use the same font, there is `cors` origin error.

Comment: If you’re able to configure the server to add a 'Vary: Origin' response header to the response, try that

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that it works for one subdomain and doesn't for the other one. 

As per documentation [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/31928.html=) you could specify *.domain.com instead of *example.com. It is a different domain.

To troubleshoot you could set allow to all domains by entering *.

More troubleshooting options can be found here [OSS Troubleshooting](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/44199.htm).